# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData Returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

```
[
    {
        "_id": "557f27522afb79ce0112e6ab",
        "endereco": {
            "cep": "asdasd",
            "numero": "asdasd"
        },
        "categories": [],
        "name": "teste",
        "hashtag": "teste"
    }
]
```

Returns nil without error :

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &erro) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: By the way, the `NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments` is unnecessary.  You could just use `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's returning `nil` without error because it's not the JSON parsing that's failing. It's failing because of the conditional type cast of the resulting object as a dictionary. That JSON doesn't represent a dictionary: It's an array with one item (which happens to be a dictionary). The outer `[` and `]` indicate an array. So, when you parse this, you want to cast it as a `NSArray`.

For example, in Swift 1.2 you could:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSArray, let dictionary = json.firstObject as? NSDictionary {
    println(dictionary)
} else {
    println(error)
}
```

Or you could cast it as an array of dictionaries:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? [[String: AnyObject]], let dictionary = json.first {
    println(dictionary)
} else {
    println(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling isValidJSONObject: or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be converted to JSON data.

isValidJSONObject(_:)
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.

Declaration
SWIFT
class func isValidJSONObject(_ obj: AnyObject) -> Bool
Parameters
obj 
The object to test.
Return Value
true if obj can be converted to JSON data, otherwise false.

Discussion
Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: You should provide an example with your answer. Thanks.